# Fullcalendar - Getting the id outside of the loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar for the first time. I have spent the day researching and problem solving and have hit a problem that I cannot work out. I have a loop running through the results of an Ajax call to populate the events. I also have a layer which appears over the event items on hover to offer edit/delete features. This all worked fine whilst I was working with static data (in testing) but now I have made it dynamic, it doesn't!

The problem is that the eventMouseOver() is outside of the loop so I'm unable to define the id. I know this is obvious but what has made me ask is that I have another variable defined outside of the loop which adds a description to the event, also using the data from the Ajax call that does work. Each description defined outside of the loop sits where it should on the different events.

Can anyone help me get the id into my inline function calls - editEvent and deleteEvent?

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'inc/scripts/expenses-scripts.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                            start: start.unix(),
                            end: end.unix(),
                            getExpenses: true,    // an option!
                            salonId: $('#globalSalonId').text(),  // an option!
                        },
                        encode: true,

                        success: function(doc) {

                            if(doc.success==true)
                            {

                                var events = [];

                                for(x=0; x<doc.event.length; x++)
                                {

                                    events.push({
                                        title: doc.event[x].description,
                                        start: doc.event[x].start,
                                        editable: true,
                                        backgroundColor: doc.event[x].backgroundColor,
                                        eventStartEditable: true,
                                        eventDurationEditable: true,
                                        description: doc.event[x].title+' - '+doc.event[x].price,

                                    });

                                }

                                callback(events);

                            }
                        }

                    });

                },

            eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc, element) {

                alert(event.title + " end is now " + event.end.format());

                if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
                    revertFunc();
                }

            },

            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, element) {

                alert(event.id + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());

                if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                    revertFunc();
                }

            },

            // I lose the event.id here //
            eventMouseover: function(event, domEvent, element) {
                var layer = "<div id='events-layer' class='fc-transparent' style='position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-2px; text-align:right; z-index:100'> <a> <img border='0' style='padding-right:5px;' src='img/pencil.png' width='10' onClick='editEvent("+event.id+");'></a><a><img border='0' style='padding-right:5px;' src='img/invalid.png' width='10' onClick='deleteEvent("+event.id+");'></a></div>";
                $(this).append(layer);
            },   

            eventMouseout: function(event, domEvent) {
                $("#events-layer").remove();
            }, 

            // ADD A DESCRIPTION TO AN EVENT //

            // I have access to the event.description here though //
            eventRender: function(event, element) { 
                element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description); 
            }
```

The data coming back in the Ajax callback is

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {

            $data['event'][$x]['start'] = $row->expenseDate;
            $data['event'][$x]['title'] = $row->expenseTitle;               
            $data['event'][$x]['id'] = $row->id;
            $data['event'][$x]['category'] = $row->expenseCategory;
            $data['event'][$x]['editable'] = 'true';
            $data['event'][$x]['backgroundColor'] = '#3399cc';
            $data['event'][$x]['eventStartEditable'] = 'true';
            $data['event'][$x]['eventDurationEditable'] = 'true';
            $data['event'][$x]['description'] = $row->expenseCategory;
            $data['event'][$x]['price'] = '&pound;'.$row->expenseTotal;
            $data['event'][$x]['allDay'] = false;

            $x++;

        }
```

Comment: can't you just set the id in your `events.push` call?

Comment: Yes @stephen.vakil. Easy as that. Thank you (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @stephen.vakil

I didn't have the id in my events array making it unavailable.

Updated code...

```
events.push({

    id: doc.event[x].id,
    title: doc.event[x].description,
    start: doc.event[x].start,
    editable: true,
    backgroundColor: doc.event[x].backgroundColor,
    eventStartEditable: true,
    eventDurationEditable: true,
    description: doc.event[x].title+' - '+doc.event[x].price,

});
```

The ID is now available